# Send an initial message when people first invite the Telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using Python and have previously built Telegram chatbot before.
However, now I want to create a chatbot such that when someone invites it, it will send an initial message that says something like "type /start for instructions".

This is to make sure that they know what to do when they first invite the bot. Can this be possibly done?

I am trying to use `bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="type /start for instructions")` but the problem is I don't know how I could obtain the `chat_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it :(

Here has another way you might interested: `/setdescription` in [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather).

It will be shown in the *What can this bot do?* section as the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After digging this issue - here's what I've found:

**The reason:**

Intuitively it seems logical to allow a feature that sends a message to a user (as a reaction to the user's action for starting the chat). BUT, because `telegram APIs` are truly vast there is a fair chance for abuse in this format (a message with button that drives the user for action without the user truly understand the consequences). From here my question changed from "how to implement this mechanism?" to "Which alternative do I have?"

**There is an alternative!**

My initial goal was to make the "what can I do here" factor as clear and effortless to the user as possible. Technically speaking - all methods that can be invoked without the `chat_id` can be invoked as part of your bot setup process and will affect all users. One option is to create a list of commands to your bot. This list will appear when the user use the `/` operator and it's a common practice among chat users. For my intention - I needed something even simpler than that and I think that the `setChatMenuButton` is very suitable. This method allows you to create a `web app` and allows the user to simply click it instead of typing text. When clicking the button it triggers a dialog that clarifies to the user what's going on and from there - it's basically your imagination that will define how the end-user will experience your process. I managed to execute this call using a wrapper that I've build (which handles the `base url` as well as `secret key`) using this code:

```
await api.get('setChatMenuButton', {
    menu_button: JSON.stringify({ 
      type: 'web_app', 
      text: 'Name of your app here', 
      web_app: { url: 'https://your-domain.com/ppp/path/goes/here' }
    }),
})
```

More about [Telegram Web Apps](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#launching-web-apps-from-the-menu-button)

And a little screenshot from my experience:

[image]